# Check if ftp service is running

Tags: java, android, ftp

I want to check if a server or ip has ftp service running before connect to it. I have the next code, however if the ftp service is not active I get: "Error: failed to connect to localhost...NNREFUSED (connection refused)"

I want to capture this error to show message if service is offline or continue if is online.

```
ftpClient.connect(localhost, 21);
Boolean temp = FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(ftpClient.getReplyCode());
Log.d(TAG,"respuesta server: " +  Boolean.toString(temp));
```

The main problem is that in line 1, logcat shows the error and the lines after it are not executed.

I don't know if with FTPClient is possible, if not, something similar to make a "telnet localhost 21" manually for example.

Note: the error is not a exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to check if a server or IP has FTP service running before [trying to] connect to it

No you don't. The best way to tell whether it's running *is* to try to connect to it. If you get a connect exception, it isn't running. No other scheme you can devise will work as well.

Comment: I don't mind to do a connection before to check it. I didn't know that  it was in the capture of the exception. Solved. Thanks.

Comment: You don't need to do *another* connection. Do the connection you want to do, and cope with the exception if it happens.